# How to set up an additional server in Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I want to set up a new Heroku server for QA purposes.
I've done most of the pieces but I've missed something:

1) I made a new app using the CLI Heroku toolbelt:

```
heroku apps:create myapp-qa
```

2) I made a copy of the existing git repostory on my local machine:

```
git clone git@github.com:me/myapp.git
```

3) Added the remote for the aq server:

```
git remote add myapp-qa git@github.com:myrepo/myapp.git
```

3) I then tried to push my new app with:

```
cd myapp

git push myapp-qa master
```

I got the message "already up-to-date"

4) If I go to the app in a browser to http://myapp-qa.herokuapp.com/ it says "Heroku | Welcome to your new app!" instead of showing any of my application pages.

What did I miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setup needed to be:

```
git remote add myapp-qa git@heroku.com:myapp-qa.git

git push origin myapp-qa
```

Answer (score 1):

Heroku has a plugin specifically designed for this.

https://github.com/heroku/heroku-pipeline

It allows you to specify a "pipeline" of servers

`Dev -> Staging -> Production` and allows you to deploy to dev, then promote that build to staging, then promote that to production.